# В чем достоинства и недостатки скрипта регистрации?

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

```
<?php

if (isset ($_POST['ok'])) {
    $name = !empty ($_POST['name']) ? trim ($_POST['name']) : NULL;

    $login = !empty ($_POST['login']) ? trim ($_POST['login']) : NULL;
    $pass = !empty ($_POST['pass']) ? trim ($_POST['pass']) : NULL;
    $city = !empty ($_POST['city']) ? trim ($_POST['city']) : NULL;
    $pol = !empty ($_POST['pol']) ? trim ($_POST['pol']) : NULL;
    $error = array();
    include 'db.php';
    $res = mysql_query ("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '".mysql_real_escape_string ($login)."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows ($res) > 0)
        $error[] = "<div style=\"color:#cc0000; width:90%; margin:15px auto; background-color:#fff9f9; border:1px solid #cc0000;padding:6px\"><small>Этот логин занят</small></div>";
    $res2 = mysql_query ("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string ($name)."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows ($res2) > 0)
        $error[] = "<div style=\"color:#cc0000; width:90%; margin:15px auto; background-color:#fff9f9; border:1px solid #cc0000;padding:6px\"><small>Это имя занято</small></div>";
    if ($pass == "")
        $error[] =  "<div style=\"color:#cc0000; width:90%; margin:15px auto; background-color:#fff9f9; border:1px solid #cc0000;padding:6px\"><small>Вы не ввели пароль</small></div>";
    if ($city == "")
        $error[] = "<div style=\"color:#cc0000; width:90%; margin:15px auto; background-color:#fff9f9; border:1px solid #cc0000;padding:6px\"><small>Вы не указали город</small></div>";
    if (!$pol)
        $error[] = "<div style=\"color:#cc0000; width:90%; margin:15px auto; background-color:#fff9f9; border:1px solid #cc0000;padding:6px\"><small>Вы не указали Ваш пол</small></div>";
    if (count ($error) == 0){
        $res3 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `login`, `pass`, `city`, `pol`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string ($name)."',
           '".mysql_real_escape_string ($login)."',
           '".md5($pass)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string ($city)."',
           '".mysql_real_escape_string ($pol)."')");
        if ($res3 === TRUE)
            echo "<div style=\"color:#green; width:90%; margin:15px auto; background-color:#f3fef5; border:1px solid green;padding:6px\"><small>Вы успешно зарегистрированы!</small></div>";
        else 
            echo "<div style=\"color:#cc0000; width:90%; margin:15px auto; background-color:#fff9f9; border:1px solid #cc0000;padding:6px\"><small>Ошибка во время регистрации</small></div>";
    }
    else {
        echo implode ('', $error);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ваш код - потенциальная дыра. Вы уж извиняйте. Вместо login можно написать любой javaScript код и выполнить его ...

Comment: @shurik , не покажите, как здесь запускается на исполнение переданный в login код ?

Comment: @avp, `<textarea name="login"></textarea>` и далее любой просмотр скрипта, где есть `echo $user->login` выведет его в чистом виде. Если там, конечно, не `echo htmlspecialchars($user->login)`.

Comment: Все равно насчет **исполнения** не понял. 

Каким образом злоумышленник может "написать любой javaScript код и выполнить его ...", как написал @shurik ?

@Sh4dow код "<textarea name="login"></textarea> " где должен исполняться ?  На сервере ? В своем браузере, с которого заходим для регистации ?

Прошу не обижаться и не искать двойное дно. Просто для себя хочу понять этот вопрос.

Comment: `<script src="http://server.ru/script.js"></script>Логин` - вот так выполняется сторонний скрипт при отображении логина.

Comment: Прошу еще раз извинить, видимо надо изучать эту область. 

И все таки: где (сервер или клиент) исполнится засланный клиентом сторонний скрипт ?

Мой лимит комментариев исчерпан. Возможно придется открыть тему, задав вопрос "Исполнение стороннего скрипта"

Comment: Разумеется, на клиенте, так как это javascript.

Comment: на счёт XSS не несите бред , он в данном куске кода данные не выводит данные полученные с формы , поэтому ваши суеверия  неуместны

Answer (score 2):

Советую объединить первые два select в один, а на php уже разбираться, в чем ошибка.
Также, используйте функцию [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), чтобы вам html-код в логин не ввели.
Плюс, нужны проверки на допустимость логина/имени/и т.п.
И, напоследок, советую подключить какой-нибудь шаблонизатор, а то html в php смотрится страшновато.

Answer (score 1):

```
Держите более защищенный (в первый раз не то закопипастила сорри):

<?php

if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login']; if ($login == '') { unset($login);} } //заносим введенный пользователем логин в переменную $login, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
if (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password']; if ($password =='') { unset($password);} }
//заносим введенный пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
if (isset($_POST['code'])) { $code = $_POST['code']; if ($code == '') { unset($code);} } //заносим введенный пользователем защитный код в переменную $code, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную

if (isset($_POST['email'])) { $email = $_POST['email']; if ($email == '') { unset($email);} } //заносим введенный пользователем e-mail, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную

if (empty($login) or empty($password)or empty($code) or empty($email)) //если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем скрипт
{
exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!"); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев

}
if (!preg_match("/[0-9a-z_]+@[0-9a-z_^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/i", $email)) //проверка е-mail адреса регулярными выражениями на корректность
{exit ("Неверно введен е-mail!");}

function generate_code() //запускаем функцию, генерирующую код
{

    $hours = date("H"); // час       
    $minuts = substr(date("H"), 0 , 1);// минута 
    $mouns = date("m");    // месяц             
    $year_day = date("z"); // день в году

    $str = $hours . $minuts . $mouns . $year_day; //создаем строку
    $str = md5(md5($str)); //дважды шифруем в md5
    $str = strrev($str);// реверс строки
    $str = substr($str, 3, 6); // извлекаем 6 символов, начиная с 3
    // Вам конечно же можно постваить другие значения, так как, если взломщики узнают, каким именно способом это все генерируется, то в защите не будет смысла.

    $array_mix = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    srand ((float)microtime()*1000000);
    shuffle ($array_mix);
    //Тщательно перемешиваем, соль, сахар по вкусу!!!
    return implode("", $array_mix);
}

function chec_code($code) //проверяем код
{
    $code = trim($code);//удаляем пробелы

    $array_mix = preg_split ('//', generate_code(), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $m_code = preg_split ('//', $code, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    $result = array_intersect ($array_mix, $m_code);
if (strlen(generate_code())!=strlen($code))
{
    return FALSE;
}
if (sizeof($result) == sizeof($array_mix))
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
}

// после сравнения проверяем, пускать ли пользователя дальше или, он сделал ошибку, и остановить скрипт
if (!chec_code($_POST['code']))
{
exit ("Вы ввели неверно код с картинки."); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев
}

//если логин и пароль введены,то обрабатываем их, чтобы теги и скрипты не работали, мало ли что люди могут ввести
$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);

$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);

//удаляем лишние пробелы
$login = trim($login);
$password = trim($password);

// дописываем новое********************************************

//добавляем проверку на длину логина и пароля
if (strlen($login) < 3 or strlen($login) > 15) {

exit ("Логин должен состоять не менее чем из 3 символов и не более чем из 15."); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев

}
if (strlen($password) < 3 or strlen($password) > 15) {

exit ("Пароль должен состоять не менее чем из 3 символов и не более чем из 15."); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев

}
$password = md5($password);//шифруем пароль

$password = strrev($password);// для надежности добавим реверс

$password = $password."b3p6f";
//можно добавить несколько своих символов по вкусу, например, вписав "b3p6f". Если этот пароль будут взламывать метадом подбора у себя на сервере этой же md5,то явно ничего хорошего не выйдет. Но советую ставить другие символы, можно в начале строки или в середине.

//При этом необходимо увеличить длину поля password в базе. Зашифрованный пароль может получится гораздо большего размера.

// дописали новое********************************************

// Далее идет все из первой части статьи,но необходимо дописать изменение в запрос к базе.

// подключаемся к базе
include ("bd.php");// файл bd.php должен быть в той же папке, что и все остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь

// проверка на существование пользователя с таким же логином
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {

exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован. Введите другой логин."); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев

}

// если такого нет, то сохраняем данные
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password,email,date) VALUES('$login','$password','$email',NOW())");
// Проверяем, есть ли ошибки
if ($result2=='TRUE')
{

$result3 = mysql_query ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);//извлекаем идентификатор пользователя. Благодаря ему у нас и будет уникальный код активации, ведь двух одинаковых идентификаторов быть не может.
$myrow3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
$activation = md5($myrow3['id']).md5($login);//код активации аккаунта. Зашифруем через функцию md5 идентификатор и логин. Такое сочетание пользователь вряд ли сможет подобрать вручную через адресную строку.

$subject = "Подтверждение регистрации";//тема сообщения
$message = "Здравствуйте! Спасибо за регистрацию на ".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."\nВаш логин: ".$login."\n
Перейдите по ссылке, чтобы активировать ваш аккаунт:\nhttp://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/activation.php?login=".$login."&code=".$activation."\nС уважением,\n
Администрация ".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];//содержание сообщение
mail($email, $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plane; Charset=windows-1251\r\n");//отправляем сообщение

echo "Вам на E-mail выслано письмо с cсылкой, для подтверждения регистрации. Внимание! Ссылка действительна 1 час. <a href='index.php'>Главная страница</a>"; //говорим о отправленном письме пользователю
}

else {
exit ("Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы."); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев

     }
?>
```

Comment: не согласен с работой с паролем.
1. Зачем его обрабатывать stripslashes и htmlspecialchars? Он в открытом виде ни храниться не будет, ни выводиться куда-либо.
2. Вы предлагаете сначала посчитать md5 пароля, потом добавить "salt" (цитата из SitePoint: Build your own database driven web site...: Security experts
call this salt...)

Comment: На мой взгляд, это бессмысленно - сначала добавьте salt а потом считайте md5 - тогда контрольная сумма одного и того же пароля на разных сайтах (с разными "salt") будут разными... Тем самым вы также сберегаете себе нервы, поскольку поле для хранения пароля превращается просто в char(32) - место, необходимое и достаточное для хранения значения md5. Большого смысла в "реверсе зашифрованного пароля" тоже не вижу...

Comment: если пароль и солят то это делают обычно так - md5(md5(Pass).SALT), если оставить так md5(Pass).SALT - то получив доступ к БД соль может быть ощеплена очень быстро :)

Comment: @gote, `md5(md5(Pass).SALT)` подбирать сложнее, в моем случае для подбора требуется два раза вычислять md5, в вашем всего один. Кое где встречал любопытные техники усложенения подбора пароля - 1000 вложенных md5 c разной солью на каждом уровне. В результате авторизация проходит медленнее, но все же терпимо для пользователя,а для человека решившего подобрать пароль - невыполнимая задача. DDoS на скрипт авторизации обходится банальным вводом таймаутов между каждыми 10 попытками авторизоваться для конкретного пользователя.

Comment: @GLAGOLA, С чего Вы взяли, что в Вашем случае "подбирать пароль" сложнее? Разберем "конкретно": md5 представляет собой 128-битную контрольную сумму. Это значит, что всего существует 2^128 различных значений, При этом не играет роли, будете ли Вы вычислять значения для отдельных символов, или для 25-гигабайтовых образов блю-рэй дисков. Таким образом, брут-форс атака на пароль будет 100% успешной при переборе "всего лишь" 2^128 текстовых строк, дающих различные значения md5. Т.е. взломщику вовсе не нужно знать точный пароль. Достаточно найти коллизию. Почитайте википедию - md5 уже взломан...

Comment: С другой стороны, при переборе "по словарю" - защититься можно только сильным паролем и тайм-аутом при, скажем 3-х неудачных попытках входа... Я прячу подсчет контрольной суммы в хранимую процедуру в MySQL. Таким образом SALT скрыт от "любопытных глаз" и без взлома сервера его не получить (веб-пользователь имеет право ТОЛЬКО на выполнение разрешенных процедур, даже SELECT не может выполнить напрямую из php) - а не зная салт, взлом "по словарю" и известному md5 - все равно что брут-форс, и без тысяч md5(md5(...))

Comment: Ну во-первых, вы не учли коллизии у md5. Во-вторых, на минуточку 2^128 это много. "брут-форс атака на пароль будет 100% успешной"- это если вы знаете каким образом был захэширован пароль, в противном случае вы выделите только коллизию для `md5(Pass).SALT` (для моего примера - `md5(md5(Pass).SALT)`). Дальше пробуете подобранную строковую последовательность на сайте - нифига. Дальнейший перебор, даже если вы каким-то образом узнали значение SALT, то вам остается подобрать md5(Pass) - соответственно 2^128, итого число вариантов для подбора в моем случае 2^(128+128).

Comment: Вообще у меня в голове блуждает мысль - что взаимодействие php с БД должно быть основано исключительно а вызове процедур из БД, в таком случае становится очень легко менять структуру БД - интерфейсы доступа (процедуры) останутся теже. Да и локи в БД быстрее проходят

Answer (score 0):

Советую заменить include на require. Поставить проверку, не пуст ли один из параметров, и если не пуст, то разрешить выполнить поиск, иначе сообщить.

Перед записью в переменные полученные данные лучше всего пропустить через регулярки, а после ещё и обрезать(кто знает какой длинны вам пришлют строку).

Answer (score 0):

1) На непустоту пришедшие параметры проверяете вначале - вот и проверяйте их там =) `!empty ($_POST['login'])` - даст ошибку (или предупреждение) в случае, если переменная `login` просто не пришла.

```
if(isset($_POST['login']) && (!empty (trim($_POST['login'])))){
    $login = trim($_POST['login'])
}
else // Обработка ошибки..
```

2) Вы заметили, что у вас куча дублирующего html для вывода ошибки?

```
<div style=\"color:#cc0000; width:90%; margin:15px auto; background-color:#fff9f9; border:1px solid #cc0000;padding:6px\"><small>...</small></div>
```

Юзайте try-catch, не зря их придумали

```
try{
    ...
    throw new Exception('Текст ошибки');
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo "<div style=\"color:#cc0000; width:90%; margin:15px auto; background-color:#fff9f9; border:1px solid #cc0000;padding:6px\"><small>".$e->getMessage()."</small></div>"; 
}
```

Comment: Хм, мне кажется использование исключений не очень хорошая идея - это не удобно со стороны пользователя сайта. Так как ему придется исправлять ошибки в заполненной форме по одной а не всем скопом сразу.

Comment: Поэтому следует использовать JS-валидаторы на клиенте, чтобы не заставлять человека ждать перезагрузки страницы и видеть, как вываливается куча ошибок
JS-валидация кстати тоже как правило по 1 ошибке - первой - выводит.
А серверная валидация по факту нужна только на случай какой-либо проблемы с JS (ну например, если отключен он у человека)

Answer (score -1):

Можно попробовать такой вариант:

```
$salt=time();
$pass=$_POST['user_passwd1'];
$passwd=md5(md5($salt).md5($pass).md5($salt).md5($salt).md5($pass));
```

Вообще, в базе должно быть два поля: salt и hashpass, которые заносятся туда при регистрации.
Затем при входе вычисляется hash по той же формуле и сравнивается.